# Ajuda em uma melhoria do While()

Tags: c, while

Gostaria de que quando o usuário apertar um caractere diferente de 'S' e 'N', informasse a mensagem "Informe um caractere válido". Poderiam me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

//Abertura da função do programa
int main(){

        //Declaração de variaveis
        float R1, R2, RS, RP;
        int contador;
        char continua;

        continua='S', 'N';
        contador=0;

        while(continua=='S'){
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");    
            printf("**** Cálculo para a associação dos resistores. **** \n");
            printf("Informe o valo de R1: ");
            scanf("%f", &R1);
            printf("Informe o valo de R2: ");
            scanf("%f", &R2);

            RS=(R1+R2);
            RP=(R1*R2)/(R1+R2);
            printf("Valor de RS: %f \n", RS);
            printf("Valor de RS: %f \n", RP);

            if(continua=='S'){
                printf("Repetindo... \n");
                printf("Tecle 'S', se deseja continuar ou \n'N' se deseja finalizar o cálculo: ");
                scanf(" %c", &continua);
                contador = contador + 1;
                printf("O bloco foi repetido %d vezes.\n", contador);
            }else {
                printf("O bloco não foi repetido.", contador);
            }
        }
        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode colocar o printf e o scanf dentro de um do/while exemplo:

```
do{
    printf("Tecle 'S', se deseja continuar ou \n'N' se deseja finalizar o cálculo: ");
    scanf(" %c", &continua);
    if(continua != 'S' && continua != 'N')
       printf("Digito inválido tente novamente");
  }while(continua != 'S' && continua != 'N');
```

Comment: No caso eu incluiria isso depois da linha  printf("Valor de RS: %f \n", RP);?

Comment: Deu certo, consegui valeu.